# CHAP authentication failed: bad username or password

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have been trying to connect my Ubuntu 15.10 to the Internet using an Ethernet cable. I have used the command `sudo pppoeconf` to configure the ADSL. The file `/etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider` contains the below details

```
noipdefault
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute
hide-password
#lcp-echo-interval 30
#lcp-echo-failure 4
noauth
persist
#mtu 1492
#persist
#maxfail 0
#holdoff 20
plugin rp-pppoe.so
nic-enp7s0
usepeerdns
user "username"
```

I have verified the user name and the password in `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`and its correct. The Internet connects properly from Windows with these credentials. However when I try `pon dsl-provider` and then `plog`, I get the below message.

```
pppd[2231]: CHAP authentication failed: bad username or password
pppd[2231]: CHAP authentication failed
pppd[2231]: Connection terminated.
pppd[2231]: Failed to disconnect PPPoE socket: 114 Operation already in progress
```

I am not sure what is wrong , some help would be very much appreciated. 
FYI , here is the outcome of `sudo ifconfig`

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:e9:17:64:fc  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:47:47:bd:fd:dc  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2247:47ff:febd:fddc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:280 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26954 (26.9 KB)  TX bytes:5714 (5.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:20731 (20.7 KB)  TX bytes:20731 (20.7 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:172.172.46.241  P-t-P:103.207.8.34  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:316 (316.0 B)  TX bytes:178 (178.0 B)
```

Comment: Does the password have special characters? It's been years since I had to contend with PPPOE, but I do remember having a hell of a time when my ISP issued me a password containing a backslash (quoting didn't help - it needed to be backslash-escaped)

Comment: thanks @steeldriver , the password does not have any special characters. But my wifi is up now and hence not wasting much time looking into this.